# How to clear cached configurations in Android Emulator 2.0's Extended Controls?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I encountered a bug that causes Android Emulator to crash every time the Extended Controls are opened (after clicking the More Options button). I have tried creating new emulators and wiping emulator data but the issue remains. This lead me to believe there is a cache containing previous configurations for Extended Controls.

Is there any way I can clear the cached configurations? Otherwise the 2.0 Extended Controls are completely useless now.

Comment: Just to be clear: you are crashing not when the emulator opens, but only when you tap the More Options button?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The emulator crashes when I tap on the More Options button, which typically opens up 2.0's Extended Controls.

Comment: You could try closing Android Studio, renaming `~/.android` (or the equivalent on Windows) to something else, then firing up Android Studio again. Since that directory is created on the fly when you first start using Studio, in theory Studio should be able to recreate it. You could then copy select files (e.g., `debug.keystore`) from your renamed `~/.android` directory to the new one, where you feel that you need to. And, if Studio cannot cope, you can always rename it back to `~/.android` and be back in your current state.

Comment: I have a similar issue where the whole Extended Controls behave really slow. Button and 1-2 seconds lag, like everything is run on the UI thread of it. Looking forward for an answer on this question.

Answer (score 39):

For android studio v2 and up (mac os):

1. Tools / Android / AVD Manager
2. Select the device to clear cache
3. Click on the small arrow at the right
4. Wipe data

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works for me but now takes a while to boot the emulator each time.
does anybody know if this is possible through the cli?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of lookup, I found that the settings are stored in registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Android Open Source Project\Emulator`.

Deleting the whole key and restarting everything didn't resolve my [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36903112/how-to-clear-cached-configurations-in-android-emulator-2-0s-extended-controls#comment61601823_36903112).
So here is your answer, hope you have better results.

Comment: Thanks for your insight for Windows. Hopefully a solution for Mac for appear soon.